# Max score with tagged works incorrectly for /questions, correctly for /search

Tags: bug, questions, search, api-v2.2

When I look for questions tagged *java* from the first week of September 2014 with a minimum score of 10 like this:

[/2.2/questions?fromdate=1409529600&todate=1410134400&min=10&sort=votes&tagged=java](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?fromdate=1409529600&todate=1410134400&order=desc&min=10&sort=votes&tagged=java&site=stackoverflow&filter=!4(S)MMv1vzH_mYK.I)

I get **four results** with scores 47, 15, 14, 10.

But, when I add `max=50` (which should change nothing) like this:

[/2.2/questions?fromdate=1409529600&todate=1410134400&min=10&max=50&sort=votes&tagged=java](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?fromdate=1409529600&todate=1410134400&order=desc&min=10&max=50&sort=votes&tagged=java&site=stackoverflow&filter=!4(S)MMv1vzH_mYK.I)

I get **zero results**.
(Ditto with max=20 which ought to return three of the four results).

The same thing with /search works correctly:

- [/2.2/search?fromdate=1409529600&todate=1410134400&min=10&sort=votes&tagged=java](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?fromdate=1409529600&todate=1410134400&order=desc&min=10&sort=votes&tagged=java&site=stackoverflow&filter=!4(S)MMv1vzH_mYK.I)
  and
- [/2.2/search?fromdate=1409529600&todate=1410134400&min=10&max=50&sort=votes&tagged=java](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?fromdate=1409529600&todate=1410134400&order=desc&min=10&max=50&sort=votes&tagged=java&site=stackoverflow&filter=!4(S)MMv1vzH_mYK.I)

both return four results with scores 47, 15, 14, 10.

Comment: Confirmed​​⁠​​⁠.